# Vibrocore visualizaition

Tags: 3d, geology, qgis2threejs

I just started to use Qgis2threejs to visualize 3D boreholes. I've been recently working with offshore shallow boreholes (2 to 4 m). Once the data input is already uploaded the holes don't pop up, just collar points.

Does anyone know what could be happen ? I've followed several tutorials but it's been impossible. Maybe the hole length is too short ?